# Using Linux On Screen Keyboard while on a full-screen tkinter window

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, debian, on-screen-keyboard

I have this tkinter window that is on fullscreen using root.attrib('-fullscreen', TRUE) and its currently running on debian os but I also want to access the on screen keyboard of the linux itself but it keeps on getting under the tkinter window when summoned. Anyone could think about the solution? Thanks

Tried to use root.geometry and it works, the on-screen keyboard pop-out since the tkinter window is not on fullscreen but i like it better on full screen for a cleaner look.

Here's the trimmed down version of the code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('OSK')
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

label = tk.Label(text="Fullscreen Window", font=("Helvetica", 20, "bold"))
label.pack(fill="x")


f1=tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Entries')
f1.place(x=0, rely=0.1, relwidth=1)

label1=tk.Label(f1, text='OSK Entry:',font=('Helvetica',18, 'bold'))
label1.grid(padx=10, pady=5)

entry=tk.Entry(f1, width=25, font=('Arial', 15, 'bold'))
entry.grid(column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
entry.focus_set()

ext=tk.Button(text='Exit', font=('Helvetica',15, 'bold'), bg='crimson', width=12, command=root.destroy)
ext.place(relx=.85, rely= .9)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If u post the code . I will try on linux.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @toyotaSupra I already posted it, if you'll try it, once you summoned the on-screen-keyboard on debian or linux it will pop out for a second but you can see it going behind the fullscreen window. It's still functional when you randomly press the bottom of the screen (where's the osk is normally placed) it registers the keys but you cannot see the keyboard physically. It works perfectly though if it's not on fullscreen and the geometry is set.

Comment: But u said "when you randomly press the bottom of the screen (where's the osk is normally placed) it registers the keys". I didn't see no issue. All I saw is exit button on right side and Entry on top left.

Comment: Here's what I see @toyotaSupra https://streamable.com/doqlqd

Comment: It's literally behind the window but still works lol, cant think of a solution

Comment: Here is link https://masterprograming.com/how-to-create-virtual-onscreen-keyboard-using-python-and-tkinter/ And you need to get touch screen monitor

Comment: https://github.com/tanishka1411/On-Screen-Keyboard-Tkinter/blob/main/on-screen%20keyboard.py

Comment: yea I also considered on making one but I just tried if I can use the system's osk for a cleaner look and lesser code. I think I'll just be using this code. tho thank you so much for the help!